# ¿Cómo concatenar renglones en una tabla HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, html5, table, innerhtml

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Django y he definido una tabla en HTML. Lo único que quiero es concatenar renglones dentro de mi tabla pero no INNERHTML no funciona, tampoco APPEND.

ARMADO DE MI TABLA

```
<table class="tabla tabla-content">
                    <tbody id="ContenidoTabla">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">CODIGO</td>
                        <td width="20%">PRODUCTO</td>
                        <td width="20%">PRECIO</td>
                        <td width="40%">FECHA</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

PETICIÓN DE JQUERY

```
    var Contenido = "";
                for (var i= 0; i < Datos.Productos.length; i++){
                    Contenido =Contenido + '<tr><td width="20%">'+Datos.Productos[i].Codigo_Producto+'</td>'+'<td width="20%">'+Datos.Productos[i].Nombre_Producto+'</td>'+'<td width="20%">'+Datos.Productos[i].Precio_Unitario+'</td>'+'<td width="40%">'+Datos.Productos[i].Fecha_Solicitada+'</td></tr>';
                }

$('#ContenidoTabla').append =  Contenido;
```

SI HAGO UN ALERT DE MI VARIABLE "Contenido" ME ARROJA LO SIGUIENTE:

```
<tr>
 <td width="20%">849412179-1</td>
 <td width="20%">Prueba</td>
 <td width="20%">1</td>
 <td width="40%">2019-08-31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="20%">849412179-2</td>
 <td width="20%">prueba 2</td>
 <td width="20%">1</td>
 <td width="40%">2019-08-31</td>
</tr>
```

¿Qué podría usar para concatenar?
Agradezco su atención

Comment: Creo que estas escribiendo mal la sintaxis de append, es esta: $(selector).append(content,function(index,html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de usar la funcion `append()` es asi:

```
$('#ContenidoTabla').append(Contenido);
```

Comment: Exacto ya que el trata de modificarla como si fuera un propiedad y otorgarle con el = la asignación de un nuevo valor

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, me han sacado de un apuro. De verdad estoy muy feliz. Tengan un lindo día

Comment: @AntonioLabra la mejor forma de agradecer a quien te ayudo es marcando la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos